# Intel compiler backwards compatible to Compaq compiler

Tags: fortran

I have a recent edition of the Intel Compiler on my computer.  However, I am trying to run an old fortran file designed to run on an old Compaq compiler.  It seems to have a problem with USE MSIMSL, USE File.f90, as well as ALLOCATE

Is there a way to have the Intel compile work as the old Compaq compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the specific Intel Fortran compiler which includes a version of the visual numerics IMSL library, then I don't think you are going to get this to work, short of either buying the IMSL library or porting the code to use something else, like Intel's MKL or whatever open source stuff you can scrape off netlib.

If you do have IMSL, then you will need to change `USE MIMSL` to `USE NUMERICAL_LIBRARIES` and then add a few compiler version specific incantations to get the IMSL inclusion to build.

The `USE` command is clearly syntactically incorrect, and the fact it worked in the DEC/Compaq compiler is probably only accidental. In Fortran 90 and 95 `USE` is intended for module importing. They should be changed to `INCLUDE`.

`ALLOCATE` is also a standard feature of Fortran 90 and 95. Without more information about what the exact nature of the problem is, it really isn't possible to suggest what might be happening.

Finally, 10 seconds with google found me [this link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/migrating-from-compaq-visual-fortran/) which discusses migrating from Compaq to Intel compilers. Perhaps it will be of use. Best of luck.